# Using GRASS GIS/QGIS to georeference TIFFs in 3D space, vertically?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, 3d, 3d-model, cross-section

I am a geophysicist working for a small shallow surface geophysics firm. We create 2D slices of the ground showing data collected from various surveys. These are generally cross sections (TIFFs) of uneven shapes.

This is what i want to do using QGIS/GRASS:

[image].

Is there a way to use GRASS GIS/QGIS to georeference these TIFFs in 3D space, vertically? If so is there a guide anywhere?

Would I have to use QGIS as part of workflow using another program (like sketchup)?

(the image is created in Discover, which I want to move away as we start to intergrate into QGIS.)

Comment: I too have this problem as a mineral exploration geochemist!  First you could convert the individual pixel values to xyz(value) csv file & use PostGIS or GRASS affine transform to move them to the correct location.  Then just symbolize them as cubes.  Then it will "look" like a raster.  Or second in grass create a null-value voxel and then code the voxel cells to the value from the points!  Or interpolate the points to a voxel model.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi Phillip, I finally found myself back on this problem after many years being too busy to try! I still would love to find a QGIS solution. I did as you suggested... and have got further but can you help with my current query... 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417216/color-rgbr-g-b-doesnt-colour-points-of-a-3d-billboard-in-qgis