# COLOR_RGB("R","G","B") doesn't colour points of a 3D billboard in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d, viewer

I have a shapefile made from a text file:

X Y Z R G B

It defines a vertical plane of points (see image). Usually (in standard symbology) I can use the function "COLOR_RGB("R","G","B")" in the expression string builder to colour these points however, this doesn't work for the 3D view.

I get the error "No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression."

Can anyone please suggest why/what I am doing wrong? and maybe help with a workaround?

Thankyou!

[image]

Comment: There apparently are no features on your layer.

Comment: That's odd though the shape file Is made up of columns with RGB values. When I have swap the XYZ columns so the points are a flat horizontal plane, I can use the same expression as above to colour the points? do I need to add special features for 3D? 

Thanks for your response?!

Comment: I just tried it on a test point data.   Under Layer Properties>>Symbology> the color_rgb works perfectly.  But under Layer Properties>>3D View the color_rgb fails and when I look under the Expression String Builder's Fields and Values I do not see any of my fields.  This seems to be a bug.  Maybe try to use Qgis2threejs pluggin.  I have had better luck with it.